# Div is null even though it has a child

Tags: javascript, debugging, dom, console, javascript-debugger

In the console I am getting the error that div cannot be appended to body because it has a value of null. Why is this? It has content.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
document.getElementsByTagName('div').innerHTML = '<img alt="pickle" 
src="images/pickle">';
div.style.visibility = "visible";
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.zIndex = "3";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems here

- Your `div` wasn't yet part of the document, so `document.getElementsByTagName('div')` will not yield that div yet
- Also `document.getElementsByTagName('div')` returns a `NodeList` instead of a single `Node`, and NodeList doesn't have `innerHTML` property.

Replace this line

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div').innerHTML = '<img alt="pickle" src="images/pickle">';
```

by

```
div.innerHTML = '<img alt="pickle" src="images/pickle">';
```

**Demo**

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = '<img alt="pickle" src="images/pickle">';
div.style.visibility = "visible";
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.zIndex = "3";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Still not working for me. Here is my page: https://enzobarrett.github.io/Test/ maybe you can see what I'm seeing in the console

Comment: @enzobarrett I have attached the demo. Ensure that you are invoking this script once you document is loaded.

Comment: @enzobarrett Include your script after the body tag.

Comment: Got it working, I using window.onload to keep it from loading early. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

actually you are trying to add properties to the div before it is present in the DOM. 
first you have to create the element the give it the attributes.
try this

```
var div = document.createElement( "div" );
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' )[ 0 ].innerHTML = ' <img alt="pickle" src="images/pickle"> ';
var divEle = document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' )[ 0 ];
divEle.style.visibility = "visible";
divEle.style.position = "absolute";
divEle.style.zIndex = "3";
```

Comment: Why do you use [0]?

Comment: actually document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' ) return an array and here we need the first element so [0]

Answer (score 0):

getElement**s**ByTagName() method returns HTMLCollection (i.e. an array of HTMLElements [ div, div, ... ]) even if it found only 1 element

```
var divarray = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
if (divarray.length >= 1) var firstdiv = divarray[0];
```